# Multiple twitter feeds on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm looking to have the latest post from several twitter accounts displayed on a web page. How would I go about doing this? As I understand it, the Twitter API looks for a specifically-ID'd div, and inserts the content there. Would I rename the divs in between API calls, or something similar? I honestly have no idea.

I currently have as follows:

```
<div id="twitter_update_list"></div>

...

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/[username here].json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1"></script>
```

Comment: Haha this isn't even for me. I'm designing a site for a few people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Twitter widget](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile) which I think they recommend using now actually doesn't work this way anymore, and you can have multiple copies on the same page. There's no reference to the blogger.js calls anymore that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just creating the widget on their site and cut and pasting the code? You can just get the different account widgets this way.

http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile